# Set default (auto) slug prefix for Tags

Tags: taxonomy, slug

Is it possible to add default prefix to the slug of each newly added **Tag**. So that full slug, would be stored in database (no rewrites).
**For example:**

- ***Name***: Tag1 -> ***Slug:*** prefix-tag1
- ***Name***: Tag2 -> ***Slug:*** prefix-tag2
- ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `created_term` or the `created_{taxonomy}` hooks which are fired just after a taxonomy term is created (the second only if it matches the taxonomy).

The following will only alter terms in the taxonomy 'my-taxonomy'. (I believe for the default tags, taxonomy should be 'post_tag').

```
add_action('created_term', 'my_add_prefix_to_term', 10, 3);
function my_add_prefix_to_term( $term_id,$tt_id,$taxonomy ) {
    if( $taxonomy == 'my-taxonomy'){
        $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
        $args = array('slug'=>'my-prefix-'.$term->slug);
        wp_update_term( $term_id,$taxonomy, $args );
    }
}
```

**Note:** From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term):

> It should also be noted that if you set 'slug' and it isn't unique then a WP_Error will be passed back

This shouldn't be a problem if you use this function *before* any terms are created, because prefixing the same string to unique slugs preserves uniquness.

Comment: **Updated:**
I don't know why, but it didn't work from the first time. But after playing with code, and going back to the your version, now it works fine.

I didn't succeed with `created_{taxonomy}` -> `created_post_tag`, but with `created_term` works fine. I use it with 'post_tag' and custom taxonomy too.
Thank you Stephen! You saved me a lot of time, I was trying to find the solution for the half a day.