# Alter post slug by a filter that is fired just after a post is created

Tags: plugins, permalinks, filters, slug

)

I found
(for example in [Set default (auto) slug prefix for Tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42550/set-default-auto-slug-prefix-for-tags))
that it is possible for example add `my-taxonomy` prefix in front of all taxonomy `slugs` (permalinks). The post is outdated now since such prefix can be now specified in WP settings.

What can't be done in settings it to specify `slug` prefix (=> modify slug) for a specific/custom post type. There are some plugins that can do that but they usually do a lot of things and I'd prefer to write a couple of lines of code that I can add to functions.php/custom plugin/mu-plugin...

In other words I'm trying to write PHP that gets fired just after a post (with defined type) is created and that alters slug from `my-new-post` to `my-prefix/my-new-post`.

I spent two days of googling / testing but I haven't been able to make it work. At least not for `post_type` `attachment`.

Could you please help me with that?

Thank you.

Best regards,

Mat

Comment: The question you linked to is for tags, not posts. Is there a reason you're asking speciifically about filters just after save? If the goal is to turn `yoursite.com/slug` into `yoursite.com/prefix/slug` then why not ask about that? There may be better solutions that have nothing to do with filtering just after post saves, especially if you want this for a CPT. What problem does adding the prefix solve for you?

Comment: Hi Tom,

Yes, the goal is to automatically adjust links from `mysite.com/photo-of-my-car` to `mysite.com/attachments/photo-of-my-car` since the attachment/media pages are using non-prefixed URLs that I'd like to dedicate for actual blog posts, not images...

And yes, you're right. I should ask a general question "how to do X" instead of asking "how to code X". Thank you ;-)

Comment: Ah then you should ask how to prefix `attachment` permalinks with `attachment`, it's a much simpler question, easier to understand, easier to answer. If your proposed solution got an answer you would still need to re-save every attachment to apply the new permalink, which is not the case with a generic permalink adjustment

Comment: Thank you! I've just posted the new question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372803/how-to-prefix-attachment-permalinks-with-attachment