# How to prefix `attachment` permalinks with `attachment`?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, slug

Could you please help me to prefix `attachment` permalinks with a custom string (for example `attachment`)

Such that `example.com/attachment-slug` becomes `example.com/attachment/slug`?

- Apply only to posts with `post_type` `attachment`
- Using PHP that can be added to a custom plugin / mu-plugin / functions.php
- Don’t worry about existing attachments – the code should alter the permalinks of new attachments

Thank you.

Kind regards,
Mat

P.S. [Related question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372723/alter-post-slug-by-a-filter-that-is-fired-just-after-a-post-is-created?noredirect=1#comment541912_372723)

Comment: Is the requirement that only new attachments be modified necessary? It makes the question much harder to solve

Comment: On closer inspection, if an attachment is attached to a post, it's permalink is `example.com/...../post-slug/attachment-slug`, there are questions/articles on changing individual attachment slugs via the UI. i believe this can be done with a rewrite rule and an adjustment to the permalink via a filter to point to the new rewritten URL

Comment: Only for new attachments.

Comment: Thank you. I found a couple of functional (I tested it) examples for changing standard post permalinks that use `add_filter('pre_post_link',...` but nothing works with non-`post` type of posts.

Comment: those filters don't change the permalink, they just change the URL WP thinks the post is at, it doesn't mean that WP will handle that URL. You could use those filters to change the posts URL to `I'm a little teapot short and stout, here's my handle here's my spout`, that doesn't mean WP's permalinks and rewrite rules were changed. Think of it like telling people you have a new address to send post to, it doesn't work if you don't physically move to the new address.

Comment: Would you be so kind and point me to article / code that adjust the permalink via a filter as you mentioned in the second comment?

Comment: If I had one handy I would have written an answer. `post_link` is purely for outputting the URL to the page. I thought i might have had a super easy answer for you, but the requirement that this only applies to new attachments is a major spanner in the works.